# why memory allocated to *p in below code

Tags: c++, c, gcc

Tried below program and when we declare pointer variable a reference is created memory need to be allocate explicitly.not able to figure out why below program is working. How *p got memory.

```
 int *p,b;
 *p = 4;
 printf("%d\n", *p);
```

Comment: It pulled it up from the depths of undefined behaviour.

Comment: but when i remove variable b, I get segmentation fault as expected. above program i tried with different numbers. working properly.

Comment: @abhi7436 which is clearly further evidence that the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: Please think about the implications of **undefined** in _undefined behaviour_!

Comment: This is very much a FAQ. And the question is similar to "if I stand in the middle of the highway, why am I not hit by a car?", to which the answer is "Cars are not obliged to hit you when they see you on the highway where you shouldn't be. But chances are very high that they eventually will if you don't move".

Comment: You get segfault when removing b, because they are stored automatically in the call stack, possibly in sequential order and so that before the area was the allocation (post-optimization). The behavior is still undefined.

Answer (score 6):

No memory is not being created for you and you are using [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  The pointer `p` was created but what it's value is is anyone's guess.  You are lucky you didn't get a run-time error.

From your comment

> but when i remove variable b, I get segmentation fault as expected. above program i tried with different numbers. working properly.

This is clear indicator that you have undefined behavior.  Adding or removing a variable should not cause a segfault

Comment: "You are lucky you didn't get a run-time error." I usually call that unlucky. Early, easy to see, crash is lucky, scribbling over some random memory isn't.

Comment: @ art Yeah I guess it depends if lucky means it ran or if it means you find a bug.

Comment: @NathanOliver Definitely the former. It is so much fun debugging corrupt backtraces at deadline, I wish I could do that all the time.

Answer (score 1):

You leave the pointer with uninitialized value. So when you dereference it (`*p`), you access arbitrary place in memory, resulting in a segmentation fault.

Point `p` at something by assigning to `p` itself (not `*p`) an address of a variable (like `&b`) or some freshly allocated memory (like `malloc(sizeof(int))`).

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to explain this, because of the fact that it's an undefined behaviour.

Anyway, p didn't get any memory allocated. Maybe it points to b, maybe to a totally different place. We can't say.

You're "lucky", that's all !

Comment: It is possible to explain (computers are deterministic, after all), it's just that the C standard states that it's undefined behaviour.

Comment: @cyphar Yeah, `p` just points to unprivileged region. This is sort of stereotype that "anything-anything may happen" and "can't be explained". No, you aren't flying to the moon and back on UB. But you probably made a great hole in main wall and your house is a dangerous place from now on.

Comment: Sure, what I wanted to say is that without knowing the compiler, OS architecture, and so on, we can't really answer his question.

Comment: @user3125367 I quite like that analogy. I might use that next time someone starts talking about undefined behaviour like it's unicorn blood.

Answer (score 0):

Here, Poiter defination is which holds address of another variable.In coding you didn't give any address like(&b), you just assigned constant to *p.SO it is no use of this (*) before p. and address p is stored just like we are defining by ordinary method like( int p=4;).Above code is running perfectly by changing value. I have user Turbo c++ compiler 4.0